# Is there anything wrong with posting example code in my question?

Tags: discussion

I am having an issue with some SQL functionality. I found a response that was close but would not exactly work in my situation. So I crafted a question where I copied the little bit of pseudo code that wouldn't work for me from the other response and then asked my question, quoting it. I got a response that Stack Overflow doesn't support "posting of example code":

> Richard: Please stop adding demos for your code. Stack Overflow does not support demo functionality for the code you posted here.  – Tim Biegeleisen [9 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920544/unique-date-with-current-timestamp#comment94683354_53920544)

What does that mean?

Comment: Please post your entire error response, word-for-word, that you received from the site when you tried to post code in your question.

Comment: Yes. The comment about posting "demos".

Comment: Hovercraft, it wasn't a "site error". See the link to it above.

Comment: Your question isn't clear as written, and you should state explicitly that the information you're receiving is in comments and not coming from the site itself.

Comment: @Richard Regarding demos you should at least know what a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, and how to provide one.

Comment: Honestly guys, I have no idea what you are talking about. I was just trying to explain why that sample code would not work for me.

Comment: @RichardBernstein: one problem with your question is that you do not directly notify Tim Biegeleisen that you have comments directed at  him, and so he has no knowledge that you have asked a follow-up question. Be sure to pre-pend any comments to  him with the `@` symbol, e.g., `@TimBiegeleisen`.

Answer (score 23):

You misinterpreted this comment.

[image]

Tim was telling you that shouldn't be posting your code as a runnable Stack Snippet, since *runnable SQL code* is not supported in Stack Overflow.

So it's fine to post example code (more than fine, actually), but if you try to post code that's not HTML, JS, or CSS; you should format as code (the button labelled *"code sample"*, not *"javascript/HTML/CSS snippet"*).

The one in the greenish circle, not the one crossed out:
[image]

Comment: OK. No problem! :). It was never meant to run. It was just a piece of pseudo code to explain the issue. Many sites have special rules about formatting code!

Comment: If that is a green freehand cicrle I need a new monitor ...

Comment: @rene Er... greenish? This samsung screen is kinda new and biggish, as soon as you move a little everything looks kinda off. Please, edit the answer with the correct color. Or edit the screenshot so the circle is green(ish). Or buy a new monitor. Whichever is easier and more in line with the holiday spirit.

Comment: @yivi I'll put a monitor on my wishlist ...

Comment: @rene I would tell you the exact model for this one so we could look at the world in the same shade of green, but on top of everything else, is kinda noisy. Put something more expensive on your wishlist. I'm sure you deserve it, or could deserve it eventually.